# Replace the hash by hashreference in Perl?

Tags: perl

I have a subroutine, which gets a hashreference as a parameter.

I can manipulate single hashvalues by reference.
I want to replace the whole hash, which the reference point at, so that everywhere, where this hash was references the changes become visible.

```
sub replace{
    my $hashref = shift;

    # can manipulate hash here
    $hashref->{key} = "newValue";

    # how to replace replace the hash here by a new hash
    $newHashRef = {
        key  => "value",
        key2 => "value2",
    };
}
```

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%$hashref = (
    key => "value",
    key2 => "value2",
);
```

`%$hashref` denotes "the hash that `$hashref` refers to", and assigning to that hash replaces its contents, just as it would if no reference was involved.

Answer (score 1):

Just assign to the dereferenced hash:

```
my $hashref = shift;
%$hashref = ();
```

Answer (score 1):

To replace the contents of the referenced hash:

```
sub replace{
    my $hashref = shift;
    %$hashref = ( key1 => "value1", key2 => "value2" );
}
```

(If it's `%hash` for a hash, it's `%{ $hashref }` for hash ref, `%$hashref` for short.)

To replace the reference itself:

```
sub replace{
    $_[0] = { key1 => "value1", key2 => "value2" };
}
```